# security exception in using routing in asp.net after doployment

Tags: asp.net

i'm using routing in asp.net ,in local host every thing good , but after deployment , when browsing menu get below exception

```
Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not 
allowed by the                            security policy.  To grant this
application the required
permission please contact your     system administrator or 
change the application's trust    level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException:
Request for the permission of type     'System.Security.Permissions.
SecurityPermission,           mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
current web request.          Information regarding the origin and 
location of the            exception can be 
identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


  [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type     'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
```

System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(String virtualPath, IPrincipal user, String verb) +42
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Abstractions.UrlAuthorizationModuleWrapper.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(String virtualPath, IPrincipal user, String verb) +14
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.GetWebObjectFactory(HttpContextBase httpContext, String modifiedVirtualPath) +159
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.Resolve(HttpContextBase httpContext, IList`1 extensions, String virtualPathOverride, IFriendlyUrlRouteSupportFunctions    supportFunctions) +220
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Abstractions.IFriendlyUrlRouteSupportFunctions.Resolve(HttpContextBase httpContext, IList`1 extensions, String virtualPathOverride) +16
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext, String pathOverride, IFriendlyUrlRouteSupportFunctions supportFunctions) +140
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) +8
   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) +233
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +60
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()   +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&     completedSynchronously) +69

any advice

Answer (score 2):

This indicates, that your application is not running with `Full trust` on your IIS, or the trust level is not high enough.

Please follow the following checklist:

1. Open up IIS
2. Click on your website on the left panel
3. Double click on .NET Trust Level in the right panels.
4. Set the Trust Level to `Full (internal)`

Comment: from where ? the host ?

Comment: Yes, where your application is running. Since this is an Asp.Net website I assume you are using an IIS on your server.

Comment: in the local host everything good but the problem in the host

Comment: Yes I am talking about your server. Not your local development machine